# Model with very high chi squared reduced

Tags: thermodynamics, error-analysis, data-analysis

I've done a latent heat experiment and measured the mass of nitrogen over time while applying heat. These are the results::

[image]

Which looks fine, most of the measures are in the linear fit. But when I calculated statistical parameters, they were horrible:

Chi-squared reduced: $131.7$

P-probabilty: $4.577*10^{-22}$

I can't figure out why. I used a weight scale with 0.01 gram resolution and a timer. I used the average reaction time and the timer error to calculate the total error in time.

I provided the heat using power. This was the experiment assumption:

[image]

$P_0$ is the power "given by room temperature", i.e. steaming of the nitrogen caused by room temperature.

Comment: your mass resolution is way too precise, and so the formula is correctly capturing that your experiment cannot explain the deviations if you have that good a resolution. How can you be so sure that your heating is uniform? It should not be easy to get uniform heating. You need to know better how much uncertainty you actually have

Comment: Isn't this result (the large $\chi^2$ and the small $p$-value exactly what we expect? After all, there is a significant dependency. The slope is not zero. Having said that, I have to admit that I never use the $\chi^2$. I thought that it is only applied to either categorical data or counts. What is the reason you do not calculate the $R^2$ of the fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believed that you should not use the $\chi^2$ goodness of fit test to judge the fit. Here is why: Using a different unit will change the result of the $\chi^2$. Therefore, you should only use it if the data is unites, e.g. a count.

To "proof" this point, let's take your data (I use slightly different data points, because I won't try to get your).

Here is my code:

```
## Setup your data:
x0    = 872.4                     # from your fit
slope = -0.01466                  # from your fit
x     = seq(0, 150, length=10)    
yTrue = x0 + slope*x 
set.seed(89)                      # to get a fixed set of random numbers
eps   = rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.07) # random error
y     = yTrue + eps               # my fake data

## Scaling:
unit = 1        # <-- this we are going to change
y    = y*unit

## Fit data (linear regression)
df     = data.frame(x,y)
lm.out = lm(y ~ x, df)
yHat   = lm.out$fitted.values

## plot:
plot(x,y)
lines(x, yHat, col='red')

## calc chi^2
chi2 = sum( (y-yHat)^2/yHat )
print( paste0('chi^2: ', chi2) )
```

Which generates this plot:

[image]

and the value

```
chi^2: 8.852e-5
```

Now suppose we are not evaluating the mass in gram, but instead in kg. This changes the code to

```
## Scaling:
unit = 1e-3
```

and yields the result

```
chi^2: 8.852e-8
```

This is **not** meaningful.

In addition, I recommend you are clearly stating to what your $p$-value is referring to. There is a $p$-value for a non-zero intercept and a $p$-value for a non-zero slope.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to remember what the $\chi^2$ is. Think about a single measurement to start. If you take that measurement and subtract the mean (in this case your model) and divide by the error (ie $\chi=\frac{x - \bar{x}}{\sigma}$), the $\chi$ would be expected to follow a normal distribution centered at 0 with standard deviation equal to 1. If your $\sigma$ is underestimated, the $\chi$ will be larger than expected and lie far out on the tail of the standard normal distribution. This is a very unlikely outcome, so your reduced $\chi^2$ (in this case with 1 degree of freedom) will be very large and your p-value very small. If $\bar{x}$ and $\sigma$ are correctly estimated, $\chi$ will be near the peak of the standard normal distribution and you will get the reduced $\chi^2\approx 1$ as expected.

For multiple degrees of freedom, the same reasoning applies to each measurement individually and you just sum up the individual $\chi^2$.

In your case, it seams reasonable that your linear model (ie $\bar{x}$) is correct, but your estimate of $\sigma$ is much too small. A useful heuristic when looking at a plot like yours is to plot the $1\sigma$ error bars and check if approximately 68% of the $1\sigma$ error bars overlap with the line.

Comment: I calculated the latent heat and it was not that far from the theory (200 from theory I got 185). So if I got you right, my model is correct, but I would expect to get more accurate latent heat because I used very good equipment. How does that happen? I didn't even measure the mass over time myself, it was done by a code in Python. Also, the computer was connected with a cable to the weight scale, so less noise.

Comment: I'm suggesting that your measurement is not as precise as you believe. The scatter of your measurements around your fit line is larger than one would expect for your error bars. This suggests that you have uncertainty in your measurements that you have not accounted for.